# Afferent and efferent coupling for JavaScript in Sonar?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, metrics, coupling

Is there a way to calculate afferent and efferent coupling for JavaScript in SonarQube?
I'm trying the project sample described in "Get Started in Two Minutes" section and I've already install the JavaScript plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is not currently possible. It will be part of the Cartography project: http://www.sonarqube.org/roadmap/